# Removing of Underline and Blue color of Link

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, underline

I am using Wordpress.
I want to Make my front page only with Post title and date of posting.
I have pasted that code:

```
<h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
```

Posted on

Kindly tell me how I can remove the underline and blue color from my post links.
Please mentioned the complete code and also where  to paste.

I read something about `{text-decoration:none;}` but not get to paste it.

Comment: There should be a configuration area in your WordPress dashboard.  You will need to add that `{text-decoration:none;}` into the CSS file where it talks about style for links.

Comment: body { text-align: left; }
#wrapper { display: block; border: 1px #a2a2a2 solid; width:90%;  margin:0px auto; }
#header { border: 2px #a2a2a2 solid; }
#content { width: 75%; border: 2px #a2a2a2 solid; float: left; }
#sidebar { width: 23%; border: 2px #a2a2a2 solid; float: right; }
#delimiter { clear: both; }
#footer { border: 2px #a2a2a2 solid; }
.title { font-size: 11pt; font-family: verdana; font-weight: bold; }

Comment: This is total text of my css file

Answer (score 4):

There are a few different types of links you can have.  Each different type will need to be styled.  You should be able to add custom CSS in WordPress by clicking on Appearance->Editor from the dashboard.

Add the following CSS:

```
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    text-decoration:none;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    text-decoration:none;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

You can find more information here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp